# Integral curve passing through two point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An integral curve of the differential equation $(y-x)(dy/dx) = 1$ passes through $(0,0)$, and $(a,1)$, then what is $a$ equal to?

I have four options:

1. $2-1/e$
2. $1-1/e$
3. 1/e
4. 1+e

I know how to draw direction field and integral curves, but I'm not sure how to draw this one. I realise that the slope would increase when I'm coming close to   $y=x$.

Also, is it true that the function won't be differentiable close to $y = x$?

Comment: did you try to solve the equation?

Comment: But the answer $\ln(1+x-y)=-y$ gives $a=\dfrac1e$

Comment: @user108128 Ah, you meant an implicit solution. Disregard my prior comment

Comment: Is substitution $y-x=u$ an advanced method. Do you allow to solve it?

Comment: @user108128 After substituting, we get $uu' + u = 1$. Then, what do we do? We haven't handled nonlinear equations in our course very much, I just know how to sketch them in some cases.

Comment: Solve $u'=\dfrac{1-u}{u}$

Answer (score 1):

$$(y(x)-x)y'(x)=1$$
$$y-x(y)=x'(y)$$
This first order linear ODE is easy to solve :
$$x(y)=c\,e^{-y}+y-1$$
The condition $x(0)=0$ implies $c=1$
$$x(y)=e^{-y}+y-1$$
The condition $x(1)=a$ implies $x(1)=a=e^{-1}+1-1$
$$a=\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z:=y-x$ so that $z'=y'-1$. This turns the equation to

$$z(z'+1)=1$$ or $$\frac z{1-z}z'=1,$$

$$-z-\log(1-z)=x+C,$$

$$-y-\log(1-y+x)=C$$ and from the initial condition, $C=0$.

Now we have to solve

$$-1-\log(1-1+a)=0$$ 
and $a=e^{-1}$.

---

Alternatively:

$$\frac{dx}{dy}+x=y$$ or

$$\left(\frac{dx}{dy}+x\right)e^y=\frac d{dy}(xe^y)=ye^y$$

and integrating,

$$\left.xe^y\right|_{(0,0)}^{(a,1)}=a\,e-0=\int_0^1 ye^ydy=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(y-x)(dy/dx) = 1$$
Multipy by $\mu(x)=e^y$
$$(y-x)e^ydy-e^ydx =0 $$
The differential is exact
$$-x+y-1-Ke^{-y}=0$$
$$y(0)=0 \implies K=-1$$
$$\boxed{x(y)=y-1+e^{-y}}$$
we have also that $y(a)=1$
$$\implies a=e^{-1}$$